# Accepting any Qt container as input parameter

Tags: c++, qt, containers

I have a method that takes a collection of values as input parameter:

```cpp
void doSomething(QVector<int> const &values) {
    for(auto v : values) {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Sometimes, the values that I want to pass to the method are in a `QSet` instead of a `QVector`. Since `doSomething` just iterates over the collection of values, I don't want to create a new `QVector` containing the values of the `QSet` just to be able to pass it to `DoSomething`: `doSomething(QVector<int>(set.begin(), set.end()))`. I want to be able to pass the `QSet` directly: `doSomething(set)`. How can I achieve this?

I considered letting `doSomething` accept a pair of iterators instead of the collection itself, but then I ran into the same issue: How can I make it accept both `QVector::iterator` and `QList::iterator`?

Now, what if the values are in a `QHash`? Can the same method accept a parameter being either `QVector`, `QSet` or `QHash`?

Comment: Why not just make `doSomething` a function template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want something that can accept multiple types not related by inheritance, just make it a template.

```
template <typename Container>
void doSomething(Container const& c)
{
    for (auto v : c) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

will work fine for any type `Container` that has suitable `begin()` and `end()` methods (or `begin(Container)` and `end(Container)` overloads).

If you want to accept iterators instead (since it's a little more flexible, allowing operation on only some subset of a container) ... template it on the iterator type instead.

---

Note that if you want to constrain the container to, for example, store `int` - it's much easier *not* to do this directly.

The direct method would be to make `Container` a template template parameter, and the function argument a `Container<int>` ... but this doesn't work nicely for containers like `std::vector<int>`, which has an additional `allocator` type parameter (it's defaulted, but still there).

The better way is to use SFINAE or `static_assert` to express the constraints you actually care about, such as `std::is_integral<typename Container::value_type>` or `std::is_same<int, value_type>` etc. (the number of defaulted type parameters `Container` takes isn't really one of them).

Comment: Thanks! Can I also specify that the container should contain `int` in the template?

Comment: It's generally better (less work and more flexible) not to do this directly. I've edited a brief discussion into the answer.